# How to center an iframe that is created via injection

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, bookmarklet

I am trying to create a bookmarklet that creates an iframe on the page you're on if you click on it.  I can get the iframe to show up but unable to make it centered on the page.

Here is the code:

```
javascript:(function(e,a,g,h,f,c,b,d){if(!(f=e.jQuery)||g>f.fn.jquery||h(f)){c=a.createElement("script");c.type="text/javascript";c.src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/"+g+"/jquery.min.js";c.onload=c.onreadystatechange=function(){if(!b&&(!(d=this.readyState)||d=="loaded"||d=="complete")){h((f=e.jQuery).noConflict(1),b=1);f(c).remove();}};a.documentElement.childNodes[0].appendChild(c);}})(window,document,"1.5.1",function($,L){
    var a = $('<iframe/>', {
        id: 'test-iframe',
        class: 'test-iframe',
        style: 'position: absolute;z-index: 99999;',
        width: '700',
        height: '500',
        src: 'http://google.com'
    });
    $('body').prepend(a);
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I got it solved.  I added "width:700px;margin-left:-350px;left:50%" to the style.  Basically just like the way I would trying to center an absolutely positioned <div/>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. I added "width:700px;margin-left:-350px;left:50%" to the style. Basically just like the way I would trying to center an absolutely positioned

Answer (score 1):

Add  `margin: 0 auto;` to the style.

You can also have the iframe in a container (e.g. DIV) which you can add `margin: 0 auto;` to.

Answer (score 0):

Within the style, give it

```
margin: auto;
```

Comment: Perhaps your `position: absolute;` has something to do with that.

Comment: nope it doesn't. 

Also, I need to have position: absolute; so the iframe shows up on top of the main site content, like so: http://d.pr/NY1q

Answer (score 0):

```
 #test-iframe {
       text-align: center;
 }
```

Comment: Would this potentially centre the alignment of the contents?